# Listener for checking the state of SlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, listener, panel, android-sliding

I want to change the visblity of an item when [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) is expanded to full screen.Is there any listener which detects whether sliding panel is full screen?I tried using this but didn't worked-

```
slidingPaneLayout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                if(slidingPaneLayout.getPanelHeight()>700)
                belowarrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 slidingPaneLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View view, float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelCollapsed(View view) {

              //here collapse
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelExpanded(View view) {
                //here it is in fullscreen
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelAnchored(View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelHidden(View view) {

            }
        });
```

Here you go and i hope it will help

Comment: Small tip: if you're not interested in all the callbacks, simply implement `SlidingUpPanelLayout.SimplePanelSlideListener` and only override the relevant bits and pieces.

Comment: if i want to hide an image when panel is fully expanded to full screen(maximun height) then i need to hide it inside onPanelExpanded()?

Comment: @murieldotCMR: What rest? The `SimplePanelSlideListener` provided by the library is exactly for those scenarios where you're only interested in one or two callbacks. As such, you only override the one(s) you're interested in; the others will remain an empty no-op. It's not required to do so, obviously, but it'll be faster to implement and reduces code clutter.

Comment: @MH. again you still will have to override the rest of method there is a difference between empty no-op and override method.

Comment: @murieldotCMR: I think you're misunderstanding my point. What I'm trying to say is that in stead of implementing the full listener interface, you can also opt to override the ['simple' implementation](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java#L249). It's less work and keeps your code cleaner. Functionally, there is zero difference, visually, there is. I.e. compare [this](https://gist.github.com/mhelder/f776772f9095f2bba86a) to your answer. Hopefully that'll clear things up.

Comment: Worth noting that for some reason, version 3.3.0 of this library omits the method "setPanelSlideListener". Downgrading to 3.2.1 resolved it for me.

Comment: This is not work anymore, now you can only override onPanelSlide and onPanelStateChanged.

Comment: @EladNava if I understand it correctly, the simply change the name to `addPanelSlideListener()`